# New id generation

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have problem that when I create some new entity, ID sequence is something like 1001, 2002, 3003, ... sometimes without any rule like 1003 and so on.

I would like have nice sequence for each table like that: 1,2,3,4,5,...

I thing thad problem started with new 1.9.0.0 S#arp projects. Project developing from 1.6.0.0 or starting 1.6.0.0 and later converted to 1.9.0.0 are OK and has good sequence.

Do you know where could be a problem?

I thing that somewhere i'll must something owerride, but I don't know S#arp so good a i don't know, where could be a problem.

Comment: Why I loose reputation on it? What is bad on this question except it looks that nobody know where could be a problem?

Comment: not sure probably the way you have framed your question.. not sure..

Comment: Thanks to both. I found something about HILO but i didn't joined it in my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the looks of it it seems you are Ids are currently being generated using a POID generator.. You can read up all about this in this post: http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/03/20/nhibernate-poid-generators-revealed.aspx

Now from the IDs you have provided it looks like it is using the HiLo generator, read up upon the same.. to give you a gist of it, each sessionFactory keeps a reserved set (can be defined) of ids that it can assign and when it runs through all the ids it gets a new set and the next high value is stored in a table in the same dB.. Thus everytime you recreate the sessionFactory it gets a new set and that is why the increment in the ids in your case this value is 1000.. I found a reference to this in the sharp architecture wiki: https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Sharp-Architecture/wiki/HiLoGenerator and looks like they set it to 1000..

I am guessing you have a similar convention defined and that is why you are seeing this.

Comment: Yes, In older projects, i had defined this convention by ex-coworker. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a nice sequence then I suggest changing your `Id` strategy to identity. However these types of generators have drawbacks such as not allowing batching and breaking unit of work strategies.

As you point out s#arp uses a `HILO` strategy which does not suffer from the drawbacks listed above. However one drawback (actually it isn't a drawback) is that your `Id's` are not sequential (1001, 1002, 2001, 2002, 3003 etc) as every time the session factory is built a new `HI` is taken from the `hilo` table. This is more evident on your development machine as you build the project many times. On a production server the gaps are less as the session factory is rebuilt less. Also you could reduce the lo to `10` rather than `100` to reduce the gaps!

IMO it does not matter that internal Id's are sequential as after all they are internal right? Also if you delete a record then gaps appear anyway!

If your table `id` is dependent on business logic then internal `id's` are not your answer and maybe you need an internal id and then a column with a unique index for you business logic `Id`.

I would ask yourself why you think sequential internal Id's are important? Hopefully you will realize that if isn't actually important enough to worry about it.